# What is the syntax for Drush 12 listing of permissions for specific role

Tags: drush

Upgrading to Drupal 10 and I am now using Drush 12.

In Drush 8, If I wanted to see what permissions a particular role had, I just ran `drush @my_alias role:list 'role'`

With Drush 12, if I use `drush @my_alias role:list` I get a list of all the roles and their associated permissions - all good.

Looking at the documentation, you now need to use the --filter option. If I want to get the permissions of just a single role, the syntax is according to the documenation is `drush @my_alias role:list --filter='rid=my_role'`.  This syntax is returning no results i.e. {  }

Testing by running `drush @my_alias role:list --filter='rid=anonymous'` i.e. exactly as per the documentation [Drush 12 Docs](https://www.drush.org/12.x/commands/role_list/) I still get an empty result.

I have tried several combinations using filter, but cannot get anything other than a blank array {  }

Individual permissions seem to work fine e.g. `drush @my_alais role:list --filter='administer nodes'`

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has just been [fixed](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/5770). It will be in whatever [release](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases) comes after `12.2.0`.

But since a role's permissions is just config you can also make use of `config:get` here:

```bash
drush cget user.role.my_role permissions
```